# How to get USB to serial cable working properly on virtual box running Bionic?

Tags: 18.04, usb, virtualbox

I have trouble connecting to a separate hardware via USB-to-serial cable.

I have added the USB-device to the USB-settings of my virtual box, and when I look at

```
$ dmesg|grep -i USB
I get 
[  901.138278] usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[  901.501024] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0557, idProduct=2008
[  901.501026] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  901.501027] usb 1-1: Product: USB-Serial Controller D
[  901.501028] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Prolific Technology Inc.
```

and if I disconnet the cable I see a message about disconnecting, so obviously my linux box notices the cable.

If I try dmesg|grep -i tty
I get

```
[    0.004000] console [tty1] enabled
[    0.004000] console [ttyS0] enabled
[    1.691343] 00:02: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
```

Which reveals that /dev/ttyUSBx is not shown like it should and I cannot connect to it with minicom.

```
$ ls -la /dev/ttyUSB*
ls: cannot access '/dev/ttyUSB*': No such file or directory
```

I also added the user to dialout group but it did not help.

The hw is ok; everything works if I start my old ubuntu 16.04 from the VBox manager.

How to get this to work?

Comment: What says it doesnt work? did you run the minicom serial setup procedure `minicom -s` ?

Comment: Where should I connect the minicom to? 
$ ls -la /dev/ttyUSB*
ls: cannot access '/dev/ttyUSB*': No such file or directory

Anyway, minicom settings (hardare flow control etc) are the same as in 16.04 box.

Answer (score 0):

Commands 'uname -a' and 'dpkg -l | grep linux-modules' showed that linux-modules-extra was missing/incorrect version.

To get it fixed,

```
bionic-vm:/dev$ uname -a
Linux bionic-vm 4.15.0-55-generic #60-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 2 18:22:20 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

sudo apt install linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-55
```

--> working now